# Replace utf8 characters

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I want to replace some `utf-8` characters set with another `utf-8` character set but anything I try I end up with errors.

I am a noob at Python so please be patient

What I want to achieve is converting characters by unicode values or by html entities (more readable, for maintanance)

**Tries (with example):**

1.First

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Found this function
def multiple_replace(dic, text): 
    pattern = "|".join(map(re.escape, dic.keys()))
    return re.sub(pattern, lambda m: dic[m.group()], text)

text="Larry Wall is ùm© some text"
replace_table = {
    u'\x97' : u'\x82' # ù -> é
}
text2=multiple_replace(dic,text)
print text #Expected:Larry Wall is ém© some text
           #Got: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

2.Html entities

```
dic = {
    "&uacute;" : "&eacute;" # ù -> é
} 

some_text="Larry Wall is ùm© some text"
some_text2=some_text.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
some_text2=multiple_replace(dic,some_text2)
print some_text2
    #Got:UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: What does "UTF-8 character" mean?

Comment: I was refering to chars like ù, Û,ë,ì etc. Or am I missing something?

Comment: is it Python2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 2

Comment: I realize that, but the "UTF-8 character" doesn't make sense, and I suppose that confusion is at the heart of your problem. Worth [reading some background](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Make sure you understand the concepts of *encoding*, *character*, *byte*, *Unicode codepoint*, and *UTF code unit*.

Comment: @danielfranca judging from the `print` statements I'd say python 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that your input strings are in non-unicode representation (`<type 'str'>` rather than `<type 'unicode'>`). You must define the input string using the `u"..."` syntax:

```
text=u"Larry Wall is ùm© some text"
#    ^
```

(Besides you will have to fix the last statement in your first example - currently it `print`s the input string (`text`), whereas I am pretty sure that you meant to see the result (`text2`)).